# When searching do "skip bottom, jump to the top" of the file

Tags: vim

The title pretty much gives the gist away. Is there a setting that will, when using <kbd>n</kbd> and <kbd>N</kbd> stop the search when the bottom of the file is reached?

Answer (score 7):

Turn off search wrapping:

```
set nowrapscan
```

It'll give an error and stop at both the top and bottom of the buffer:

```
E384: search hit TOP without match for: set
E385: search hit BOTTOM without match for: set
```

From [`:h wrapscan`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27wrapscan%27): (default on)

```
Searches wrap around the end of the file.  Also applies to ]s and
[s, searching for spelling mistakes.
```